# Реализация инвентаря на php в браузерной игре

Tags: php, html, mysql, разработка-игр

очень прошу помочь новичку в создании инвентаря для браузерной игры.

Есть таблица users, где прописаны текущие координаты, локация, id пользователя. Для каждого из этих пользователей где-то нужно хранить данные по их инвентарю.

Если сделать одну таблицу для всех пользователей это будет вызывать подвисание?

Добавлено: какой столбец лучше проиндексировать для поиска?

Как можно реализовать инвентарь так, чтобы он был разделён для каждого игрока (просто текстовый инвентарь с неограниченной вместимостью)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: «это будет вызывать подписание?» — если расставите адекватные индексы, то не будет

Comment: Можете проинформировать, как именно расставить адекватные индексы? Допустим у предмета есть уникальный id и owner_id, то есть мне проиндексировать owner_id, и извлекать данные пользуясь WHERE owner_id='.$owner_id.'?

Comment: *какой столбец лучше проиндексировать для поиска?* Сначала соберите ВСЕ шаблоны запросов в эту таблицу. Оценочно - проставьте процент каждого шаблона в общем потоке. Только после этого можно хоть как-то прогнозировать, какой или какие индексы следует создать.

Comment: `новичку` ... `одну таблицу для всех пользователей это будет вызывать подвисание?` бд рассчитаны под миллионы записей\пользователей, сильно сомневаюсь что у вас(новичка) столько есть чтоб прямо сейчас сильно париться о подвисаниях, к тому моменту когда наберется народ, успеете наизусть выучить все способы оптимизации, если захотите. и к слову, стоит определиться будет ли прокачка\заточка предметов. без неё, предмет в инвентаре это лишь ссылка на шаблон, с ней - еще и куча собственных параметров на каждый прокачиваемый предмет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря советам из комментариев реализовал так:

Создал таблицу inventory, в которой добавил id предмета, его владельца(foreign key с таблицей user), характеристики. Также проиндексировал по столбцу owner_id, отображение инвентаря происходит довольно быстро и без подвисаний. Спасибо всем комментаторам!